# Computed property not updaing UI in different tabs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

- I use **vuex** for state management and authenticate users with
  **firebase**
- I use [vuex-persisted state](https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate) to save the state in cookies

In my vuex store I manage my **userdata**(user name , logged in status) as below

**my store.js**

```
/all imports here
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
   state : {
    user: {
        loggedIn: false,
        userName: 'Guest'
    }
},

getters : {
    g_user: state => {
        return state.user;
    }
},

mutations : {
    m_logInUser: (state, userName) => {
        state.user.loggedIn = true;
        state.user.userName = userName;

    },
    m_loggedOut: (state) => {
        state.user.loggedIn = false;
        state.user.userName = 'Guest';
    }
},

actions : {
    a_logInUser: ({state, commit}, userInput) => {
        //call to the API and on success commit m_logInUser mutation
    },
    a_loggedOut: ({commit}) => {
        //call to the API and on success commit m_loggedOut mutation
    }
},
plugins: [
     createPersistedState({
         paths: ['authStore.user'],
         getState: (key) => Cookie.getJSON(key), 
         setState: (key, state) => Cookie.set(key, state, { expires: 3, secure: false })
     })
]
});
```

**now the problem I am facing**

- when I open the app in two different tabs and login the user in 1st tab , the user logs in which now hides the login buton and shows logout button and shows the username
- but in the 2nd tab its still showing the login button , but when i console.log for the user, it shows logged in and also the username

**here is my header.vue component**

```
<template>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <router-link to="/" tag="a" class="navbar-brand">Brand</router-link>
 </div>
  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li @click="testmethod"><a>cuser</a></li>
        <router-link to="/statuses" active-class="active" tag="li"><a>Status</a></router-link>
        <router-link to="/users" active-class="active" tag="li"><a>Users</a></router-link>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" v-if="!g_user.loggedIn">
      <router-link to="/signup" active-class="active" tag="li"><a>Signup</a></router-link>
      <router-link :to="{name: 'login'}" active-class="active" tag="li"><a>Login</a></router-link>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" v-else>
        <router-link to="/post" tag="li"><a><button class="btn btn-info">POST</button></a></router-link>
        <router-link to="/current" active-class="active" tag="li"><a>{{ g_user.userName }}</a></router-link>
        <li @click="logOut"><a>Log out</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
export default{
    methods: {
        logOut(){
            this.$store.dispatch('a_loggedOut');
        },
        testmethod(){
            var user = this.$firebase.auth().currentUser;

        console.log(user);
        console.log(user.email);
        }

    },
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters([
            'g_user'
        ])
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, I am reaching the same situation you had and just want to confirm that, does the vuex-persistedstate & vuex should update the state across multiple tabs once it's updated from any one tab? This is quite important for logged status check. For example, if a user proceed to checkout, and logout in another tabs, the user should see a pop-up says "you're logged out" when switched back to the checkout tab.

Comment: It's been a while since I looked into that project. But as far as I remember the solution worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `watch` your Vuex state:

```
mounted() {
  this.$store.watch(
    function(state) {
      return state.g_user.loggedIn;
    },
    function(value) {
      if (value === true) {
        console.log('user is logged in');
        // do your logic here, setup loggedin behavior hooks. For example call login() function which should first check if the user is already logged in
      }
    },
    {
      immediate: true
    }
  );
},
```

Comment: But whats wrong with using computed...it also return the value whenever the property its depending on changes right,,,

Comment: Nothing wrong with it, but in this case you also have to call a function upon component creation (created or mounted hook), and in this function check logged-in status and initialize proper state values, so that getters return proper things

Comment: I've not used vuex-persistedstate, but I guess you should call something like this.$store.createPersistedState() in order to load saved data. Not sure.

Comment: i load the state of the user login in cookies using vuex-persitated state